# virtual function design issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class where currently I have a method called get_value() which should return values converted appropriately to various primitive data types. Since, we cannot have virtual methods which differ by only return types, I had to do the following:

```
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, unsigned char & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, char & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, unsigned short & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, short & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, unsigned int & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, int & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, float & r) const = 0;
virtual void get_value(unsigned int index, double & r) const = 0;
```

This is quite annoying from a maintenance point of view and also the usage is a bit awkward as the user has to do something like:

```
unsigned char v;
obj->get_value(100, v);
```

Anyways, the fact that all the child classes have to override for each of these types is annoying. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions to avoid this or somehow be able to do this in a more compact way by having just one virtual function somehow.

A child class could be something like:

```
void get_value(unsigned int index, unsigned char & r) const {get<unsigned char>(index, r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, char & r) const {get<char>(index, r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, unsigned short & r) const {get<unsigned short>(index, r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, short & r) const {get<short>(index, r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, unsigned int & r) const {get<unsigned int>(index,r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, int & r) const {get<int>(index,r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, float & r) const {get<float>(index,r);}
void get_value(unsigned int index, double & r) const {get<double>(index,r);}
```

where this specialised templates get method does something specific for each child class.

Comment: Do the methods really need to be virtual ?

Comment: Can we see an implementation example of this class? How do you store this polymorphic value?

Comment: The method does need to be virtual as each of the child classes work over multidimensional arrays and other specialised nuances.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I have edited the post to show a sample child class implementation.

Comment: I think we are lacking context here. **Why** do you have all those methods to start with ? It seems to me that *a single type* should exist at a given index, so why does a class allow to read *multiple types* from the same emplacement. If you step back in your presentation and present the context in which this class is used, then we might be able to offer better.

Comment: Agree with Matthieu, you might want to consider whether this problem is not an artifact of your solution to the real problem to solve.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider just creating different functions.

```
int getInt();
double getDouble();
```

And so on.

It seems that your calling code **has to know the difference in any case**. Since there is no real abstraction on the operations you can perform (apparently, at least), you may as well make the difference clear. Templates and object-oriented classes may just add needless complexity.

Of course, in order to judge this, one would probably need more context. Just my 0.02 € :)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a **look at [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)**. They will allow you specify the type like so:

```
foo<float>(bar); // calls the float version
foo<int>(bar); // calls the int version
```

Comment: You were faster than me! I actually think this is the best way.

Comment: Ooh. I like that better than the answer I am no longer going to post.

Comment: Me too but we still need to specialize it for every expected return type.

Comment: Unfortunately, member function templates can't be virtual, so there's no way to override them in the derived class.

Comment: I have the feeling that a class that needs all those get_values function can be templated in other functions, so the class, and not the member functions are templated, and that can be used with inheritance.

Comment: @EricFortin if you want different behaviour for each one, you're going to have to specify it somewhere somehow.

Comment: @JaviV Agreed, it's like having a Vector2 type with template member functions everywhere (i.e. not good)

Comment: I cannot use templates as they cannot be overloaded :-(

Comment: @Luca yes they can, I have done it few days ago, take a look at this code: https://github.com/jvgomez/fastmarching/blob/master/fmm/sfmm.hpp

I mean templated classes, not member functions.

Comment: @Javi: You can inherit from a templates base but you cannot override templates virtual methods. In your example, I do not see where you have overridden templates methods or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant that you can override template classes, not methods. However, is not a possible solution to template the whole class instead of just that function?

Comment: No, of course not...coz you have the template over the basic data type but this function has many different return values (I am having return types for all basic data types).

Comment: @Lucas out of interest, how do you plan on getting the data when your return type is void?

Comment: @OMGtetchy: the value is returned in the second parameter which is passed by reference if you look in the code snippet I provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single virtual function call that returns a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) like this:

```
using vartype = boost::variant<
    unsigned char,
    char,
    unsigned short,
    short,
    // ...
>;
virtual vartype get_value(unsigned int index) const = 0;
```

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: 1) You need to know what type to read (its size, so on). 2) `boost::any` only hides a variable type, but it doesn't allow to convert between types.

Comment: @IvanGrynko, Not with `boost::variant`.

Comment: Unfortunately using boost is not an option on this project :-(

Comment: @Luca: `boost::variant` is just a `union` with some sugar-coating over it, you can certainly work out from this concept.